# Set width of child to parents width including border

Tags: html, css

How can I set the width and the alignment of the `.inner` class to match the width of its parent?

Possible solutions would be:

- set `box-sizing: content-box` and `left: -1px`(border size)
- set `left: -1px`and `right: -1px`

But I think these solutions are not perfect because you have to know the border-size of the parent and/or you have to work with `box-sizing: content-box` but i want to avoid this.

Furthermore I can´t just change the DOM hierarchy because I want to restyle elements which are generated by a JS-framework

**Do you know any better solutions?**

```css
*, *:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.outer{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  }

.inner{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  // box-sizing: content-box;
  // left: -1px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  text
  <div class="inner">Inner</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to use the [css3 `outline` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline), which can function similarly to `border`, but does not add width to the element.

Comment: yeah i already tried it with outline but i got additional borders between some divs which i did not want

Comment: Ah, that is unfortunate. I don't know of any alternative solutions other than those you listed, excepting doing something ridiculously overkill such as modifying the DOM via Javascript post-generation.

Comment: i just noticed that i added the outline property to a class which was on multiple divs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is this:

(All other settings don't really help - you *have* to have the `left: -1px;`, there is no way to link it to the border thickness.

```css
.outer{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  }

.inner{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: -1px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  text
  <div class="inner">Inner</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.outer{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  }

.inner{
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

Is this what you are looking for? You can use the outer div's border, since it is already positioned at the bottom and stretched out to the width of the outer div.

All you need is `border-top: 1px solid #000;`.